# PIC getting each bit value of an integer value

Tags: pic

I need to send some integer value that is between 0 and 100 to another PIC by using 8 bits of PIC18F26K83. The problem is pins are from different ports not from the same ports. So I cannot follow a way like: PORTA = integer number.

1. bit should be sent to RC0.
2. "  ""      "   "   " RC1.
3. "  ""      "   "   " RC5.
4. "  ""      "   "   " RC6.
5. "  ""      "   "   " RC7.
6. "  ""      "   "   " RA5.
7. "  ""      "   "   " RA6.
8. "  ""      "   "   " RA7.

How can I make it from the easiest way? I couldn't accomplish it with bit shifting because I could not get individual bit by using that way except the first bit.

Edit: In C language and I use Micro C compiler. I thought I could make bitwise and operation but that might be unnecessarily long.

Comment: Note that if your number is less than 128 the top bit will always be zero, so you only need to wire up 7 pins.

Comment: Bit-shifting should work. Edit your question to show is what you tried and maybe someone could tell you where you're going wrong.

Comment: Has the connection already been wired up?  Because it would be significantly more efficient to use the order C0,C1,A5,A6,A7,C5,C6,C7.

Comment: Yes its already been wired up :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build up the byte from arbitrary bits like this:

```
uint8_t temp; 

temp = 0; 
if (bit_1) temp |= (1 << NUMBER_OF_BIT_1) ;
if (bit_2) temp |= (1 << NUMBER_OF_BIT_2) ;
...
if (bit_7) temp |= (1 << NUMBER_OF_BIT_7) ;
LAT_X = temp;
```

You could also set/clear the latch bits directly if you don't care about glitches during the calculation.

The numbers (1 << NUMBER_OF_BIT_x) are converted into constants during compilation/pre-processing so there is no wasted time in specifying them in a readable manner.

Comment: Or does this way would work too?

Comment: LATC.B0 =number &0b00000001;
           LATC.B1 =number &0b00000010;
           LATC.B5 =number &0b00000100;
           LATC.B6 =number &0b00001000;
           LATC.B7 =number &0b00010000;
           LATA.B5 =number &0b00100000;
           LATA.B6 =number &0b01000000;
           LATA.B7 =number &0b10000000;

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I could not try it yet

Comment: Eeks, don't do 8 individual bits when there are 3 groups of adjacent bits.

Comment: @BenVoigt depends on how it compiles- if it compiles into a string of btfc/bsf instructions it would be very fast- no barrel shifter on those little MCUs.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Oh I forgot the "no barrel shifter".  Still seems like `PORTC = (PORTC & 0x1C) | (data & 0xE3)` turns into fewer than the 10 instructions for setting those 5 bits individually.  But it isn't interrupt-safe :( The other 3 bits I suspect you're right that lacking a barrel shifter makes it more efficient to do one-at-a-time.